# SQL: how to find unused primary key

Tags: sql, performance, primary-key

I've got a table with > 1'000'000 entries; this table is referenced from about 130 other tables. My problem is that a lot of those 1-mio-entries is old and unused.

What's the fastet way to find the entries not referenced by any of the other tables? I don't like to do a

```
select * from (
select * from table-a TA
minus
select * from table-a TA where TA.id in (
select "ID" from (
   (select distinct FK-ID "ID" from table-b)
union all
  (select distinct FK-ID "ID" from table-c)
...
```

Is there an easier, more general way?

Thank you all!

Comment: It's fugly, but you could try to delete them and let referential integrity cause a fail for those that are referenced.

Comment: backup the table and try deleting everything. If there's a foreign key the referenced rows will fail to delete.

Comment: If you try to delete everything and there's a foreign key constraint in place then ALL rows will fail to delete if there is at least one row being referenced - not just the referenced rows. You could try to delete each row individually I suppose but that probably isn't very practical unless the table is quite small.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select * from table_a a
 where not exists (select * from table_b where fk_id = a.id)
   and not exists (select * from table_c where fk_id = a.id)
   and not exists (select * from table_d where fk_id = a.id)
   ...
```

Comment: hm... I think I applaused too early... with only a few tables, your solution has lower costs; but if I use it with all the 130 tables, the costs explode: with the solution above, I've got costs of 3'000'000, with the statement from above 'only' 700'000...

Comment: @swalkner : What database system are you using?  And do the foreign tables have indexes covering the foreign_key_id?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11; most of the foreign tables do ***not*** have an index on the according column

Comment: @swalkner: In general it is highly recomended that a foreign key be covered by an index. It is normal, after all, to join on that key and so an index will yield significant performance benefits. In the case of this answer, for example, I'd expect benefits of several orders of magnitude. If applying the index is not possible, it all comes down to Oracle's best guess on what algorithm is best placed to solve the SQL when looking at unsorted tables. You'll need to use trial and error to establish what is best there.

Comment: An alternative is to accumulate rows to keep in a temp table, by inserting rows from table_b, table_c, etc., one at a time, then finally deleting any rows in table_a that aren't in the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select a.* 
from table_a a
left join table_b b on a.id=b.fk_id
left join table_c c on a.id=c.fk_id
left join table_d d on a.id=d.fk_id
left join table_e e on a.id=e.fk_id
......
where b.fk_id is null 
and c.fk_id is null 
and d.fk_id is null 
and e.fk_id is null 
.....
```

you might also try:

```
select a.* 
from table_a a
left join
    (select b.fk_id from table_b b union
     select c.fk_id from table_c c union
     ...) table_union on a.id=table_union.fk_id
where table_union.fk_id is null
```

This is more SQL oriented and it will not take forever like the above solution.

Comment: hm... I don't know if this is faster... after 26 columns, the costs are already @150'000...

Comment: it should be faster considering you do not select all from all tables because then the performance will be affected by the system's memory. I also suppose that you have indexes on the joined fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about efficiency but:

```
select * from table_a 
where id not in ( 
    select id from table_b
    union
    select id from table_c )
```

If your concern is allowing the database to continue normal operations while you do the house keeping you could split it into multiple stages:

```
insert into tblIds 
    select id from table_a
    union
    select id from table_b
```

as may times as you need and then:

```
delete * from table_a where id not in ( select id from tableIds )
```

Of course sometimes doing a lot of processing takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Patrick's answer above, but I would like to add to that.
Rather than building the 130-step query by hand, you could build these INSERT statements by scanning sysObjects, finding key relations and generating your INSERT statements.

That would not only save you time,  but should also help you to know for sure whether you've covered all the tables - maybe there are 131, or only 129.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to Marcelo Cantos' answer (and have upvoted it), but here is an alternative in an attempt to circumvent the problem of not having indexes on the foreign keys...

```
WITH
  ids_a AS
(
  SELECT id FROM myTable
)
,
  ids_b AS
(
  SELECT id FROM ids_a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE fk_id = ids_a.id)
)
,
  ids_c AS
(
  SELECT id FROM ids_b WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE fk_id = ids_b.id)
)
,
...
,
  ids_z AS
(
  SELECT id FROM ids_y WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_y WHERE fk_id = ids_y.id)
)

SELECT * FROM ids_z
```

All I'm trying to do is to suggest an order to Oracle to minimise its efforts.  Unfortunately Oracle will compile this to comething very similar to Marcelo Cantos' answer and it may not performa any differently.

Comment: interesting... but I think the same problem here... costs are rising fast... after three tables I've got costs of 18'000... is it possible that they are misleading? according to the costs, "right anti" is the most expensive operation...

Comment: If it's an estimated explain plan, the results could be mis-leading.  It's effectively having to predict the number of records being processed at each stage.  If it's an actual explain plan, it's going to be reasonably representative.