# Check if entity has dependencies in Code First

Tags: reflection, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I'm trying to check if my entity has any dependencies before allowing deletion:

Normally we can do this for each entity type by doing this:

```
public class Company{
   public int id;
   public string name;
   public virtual IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Building> Buildings {get;set;}
 
   public bool hasDependencies => Departments.Any() || Buildings.Any();
}
```

But I want to do this generically for any nagivational properties an entity could have

Note: Lazy loading is enabled.

```
public bool HasDependencies()
{
   int ExampleEntityId = 2; // just example
   Company companyEntity = _unitofwork.CompanyRepository.GetEntityById(ExampleEntityId);

   IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoList = _unitofwork.CompanyRepository.GetNavigationProperties();

   bool dependenciesExist = false;
   foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfoList)
       {
            dependenciesExist = companyEntity.**property**.Any(); //This obviously doesn't work, but just to convey the intent.
            if (dependenciesExist) {
                    break;
            };
        }
            return dependenciesExist;
}
```

This is the GetNavigationProperties method:

```
        public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNavigationProperties() 
        {
            var modelData = _context.Model.GetEntityTypes(typeof(TEntity)).ToList()[0];
            var propertyInfoData = modelData.GetNavigations().Select(x => x.PropertyInfo);

            return propertyInfoData;
        }
```

I've looked in many pages including the following to figure this out:

[EF5 How to get list of navigation properties for a domain object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886725/ef5-how-to-get-list-of-navigation-properties-for-a-domain-object)

[Check if entity has references in other entities in Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872136/check-if-entity-has-references-in-other-entities-in-code-first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rely on materialized entity instances with loaded navigations (lazy, eager or explicit), you can easily simulate the `Any` check on collections since all they can be cast to `IEnumerable<object>`, e.g.

```cs
dependenciesExist = property.GetValue(entity) is IEnumerable<object> collection
    && collection.Any();
```

But note that `GetNavigations()` API does not return skip navigations (i.e. EF Core 5.0 introduced many-to-many via implicit join entity) - these are returned by `GetSkipNavigations()` API. At the same time `GetNavigations()` returns bot collection and reference navigations, so if you need to filter them out, or process them separately, you'd better return EF Core metadata objects rather than reflection parts. e.g.

```cs
var entityType = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));

var collectionNavigations = entityType.GetNavigations()
    .Where(nav => nav.IsCollection)
    .Concat<INavigationBase>(entityType.GetSkipNavigations());

var referenceNavigations = entityType.GetNavigations()
    .Where(nav => !nav.IsOnDependent);
```

For reference navigations, you simply do `null` check

```cs
dependenciesExist = property.GetValue(entity) != null
```

and for collections (both skip many-to-may or regular one-to-many) do the `IEnumerable<object>` check as shown at the beginning.